# is this going to work in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, swift

I have this property in my class:

```
var feeds = NSMutableArray()
```

then I use it in a method:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
        return self.feeds.count
}
```

When I Option+Click on the "count" it says it is available in iOS 8 and later.

I think I read somewhere that most of the functionality written in Swift should still work in iOS 7 (unless we are using iOS 8 APIs, of course).

So I am just wondering, is this supposed to work in iOS 7 as well or not? And if yes, why the quick docs tells me that it is supported on iOS 8 and later.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the actual documentation for the [count method in Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIVector_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CIVector/count).

`- count`
Returns the number of items in a vector.

### Declaration

**SWIFT**

```
func count() -> UInt
```

**OBJECTIVE-C**

```
- (size_t)count
```

**Return Value**

The number of items in the vector.

```
Import Statement
import CoreImage

Availability
Available in iOS 5.0 and later.
```

What you are looking at is the method's **Quick Help** info and it says *"iOS8 and later"*, but this doesn't matter because you app should work on iOS 7 without any problem, even in my dummy project to test this I could build and run the code on both OS versions without warning.

**Question:** Why are you using `NSMutableArray` to initialize your variable and you are not just using the Array Swift declaration?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I use "NSMutableArray" just to make it super-clear that I am using a class available in Objective-C and that works in iOS 7 for sure.

Comment: Don't worry about it, I'm working right now on SpriteKit project using Swift and using all the build in Swift types for my data structures. I always build the project for iOS 7.1 and everything works great. Also, check this from the Apple docs *"Swift automatically bridges between the Array type and the NSArray class."*